# Convertir un tipo entero a caracter según el valor del entero

Tags: java, poo

Tengo que realizar las torres de hanoi en java. Tengo un problema a la hora de imprimir los discos. Me han pedido que el valor del disco se transforme en *.
Ejmplo: Si mi disco tiene un tamaño de 4 que se conviertan en ****, el valor del disco es de tipo entero y me lo pasa el usuario por pantalla.
Estoy intentado pasar el (int)valorDisco a String para depués convertirlo en *; utilizando el metedo de la clase String replace, pero me cambia por número de cifras no por valor del número.

```
f(tamayoDiscoConvertir > 0) {

            String valorDisco = String.valueOf(tamayoDiscoConvertir);

            valorDisco.replaceFirst(valorDisco, '*');
        }
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: Si el usuario te introduce el tamaño, ¿Por que no utilizas (por ejemplo) un bucle `for` que rellene de `*` hasta máximo el valor introducido por el usuario. Creo haber entendido así la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y tampoco hace falta controlar que `tamañoDisco` sea mayor a cero

```
int tamañoDisco =3;//este es el valor que te pasan
String tamanioDiscoConvertir ="";

for (int i = 0; i < tamañoDisco; i++) {
    tamanioDiscoConvertir =tamanioDiscoConvertir.concat("*");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia, no es necesario convertir a String el tamaño del disco, basta con agregar un * a una variable String al recorrer el tamaño del disco. Tomando como ejemplo lo siguiente:

```
if(tamanoDisco > 0)
{
    String valorDisco= "";
    for(int i = 0; i < tamanoDisco; i++)
    {
        valorDisco += "*";
    }
}
```

Saludos.